Tips for how I can proceed with my Lie theoretical problem?
$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$I am looking at a map from a Lie group into a Lie algebra $\phi$:
$$\phi: \SL(n)\rightarrow \mathfrak{sl}_n$$
$$ P \rightarrow U_1^\dagger P U_1 + U_2^\dagger P U_2.$$
$P$ denotes the generalized Pauli elements without the identity, $U_i$ denote unitary matrices. The goal is to characterize $U_i$ such that this is 0:
$$U_1^\dagger P U_1 + U_2^\dagger P U_2=0.$$
I have thought about this a lot. First, I thought that this may be an adding of adjoint representations:
$$\phi(P)=(\operatorname{Ad}_{g_1*}+\operatorname{Ad}_{g_2*})P.$$
But I don't know if you can simply add adjoint representations and what this means mathematically (where does $(\operatorname{Ad}_{g_1*}+\operatorname{Ad}_{g_2*})$ live?). Since, at the end, it is this "space" that I will be investigating.
Then I thought one could look at this as:
If $$\phi(P)=0 \Rightarrow \exp (U_1^\dagger P U_1 + U_2^\dagger P U_2)=\mathrm{Id}\in \SL(n)$$
and this indicates that, for $L^P$ being the associated left-invariant vector field to my Lie algebra elements $P$, which happens to be simultaneously an element of its associated Lie group $P\in \SL(n)$, $P\in \mathfrak{sl}_n$
$$l_{P^{\dagger}}P=\mathrm{Id}\Rightarrow l_{P^{\dagger}*}P=l_{P^{\dagger}*}L^P_e=L^P_{P^\dagger}=0.$$
But I am not sure if this equality is right, since this would mean that my vector field vanishes at $P^\dagger$ and even if so, I don't see how this helps me.
Another way of looking at this problem could be by looking at this as a unitary conjugation representation acting on my Lie group $\SL(n)$ but then, again, since this map does not map $\SL(n)$ to $\SL(n)$ I am not sure if this is adequate. And $\phi$ is not homomorphic, which makes it harder to look at from a transformation group theoretical perspective.
Please help me for this, I am really kind of stuck here.

I don't see how your map has image in $\mathfrak{sl}n$. Do you mean for there to be a minus instead? If so you are just requiring that $\mathrm{Ad}{U_1}(P) = \mathrm{Ad}{U_2}(P)$ or said another way $\mathrm{Ad}{U_2^U_1}(P) = P$, that is, $U_2^ U_1$ is in the stabiliser of $P$. If you do mean it as written (and thus not a map into $\mathfrak{sl}n$) then you are looking at $\mathrm{Ad}{U_2^*U_1}(P) = -P$ which won't be possible for all $P$ (I think for $n$ odd it is completely impossible for any $P$)

It is a map into $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. Note that this can be identified with the space of traceless matrices of $n$ dimension. Clearly, $\phi(P)$ is traceless.

$\phi(P)$ doesn't look traceless to me, but, as @Callum said, it would become traceless if the $+$  sign were changed to a $-$ sign.

@AndreasBlass  It is traceless. $\mathrm{Tr}(U^{dagger} P U}= \mathrm{Tr}(P)=0$ since the generalized Pauli elements without the identity are traceless.

Maybe it is important to note that I do not mean the Gell-Mann representation of Pauli but the Sylvester representation

But that doesn't make your map overall a map into $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, only when you are restricting it to certain elements. Indeed it would make more sense as a map from $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ in that case. Regardless, as I said before it cannot have $\phi(P)=0$ in odd dimension, since it would require $P$ and $-P$ to be in the same orbit but $\det -P = -\det P$ in odd dimension.

Ah but this is interesting, because I was thinking about this as well, on what domain to take. So it is actually a map from $\mathfrak{sl}$ to $\mathfrak{sl}$ you say? This was what I considered it to be the last days, but my problem is that I am not considering $\sum_i \alpha_i P_i$ terms, therefore I thought the algebra would be too „large“ of a domain. What do you think about that? @Callum

I think the problem here is that it is a little unclear why you want this map and thus what properties it is supposed to have. It is well defined as a map on the set of all $n\times n$ matrices but only has image in $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ if the domain is in $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. Indeed $\mathrm{tr}\phi(P) = 2\mathrm{tr}P$. I strongly suspect there are few, if any, values for which $\phi(P)=0$  (possibly depending on choice of the $U_i$). So the question is what are you hoping to accomplish with this function $\phi$?

You are right, the domain should be $\mathfrak{sl}$, because otherwise the image would not be traceless in general.
I don't want this map, I have it in a paper and my task is now to look for characteristics that $U_i$ have to fulfill for this map to map every non-identity Pauli element to 0. As you said, it will depend on $U_i$ for this to work. I am looking how exactly $U_i$ has to be.

A title about the contents would be more useful. The only information conveyed by the title is the broad "Lie theoretical problem".

Collecting my comments into more of an answer.
The map as described doesn't have image in $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ but if you change its domain to $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, then it would work. However, note that if the map $\phi$ is $0$ on each Pauli element then it would be $0$ everywhere on $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ as the Pauli elements form a basis (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $\phi$ is clearly linear.
It is impossible for this to work for any odd $n$ as $\phi(P) = 0$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Ad}_{U_1^\dagger U_2}(P) = -P$ and for $n$ odd $\det -P = - \det P$.
For $n$ even it is certainly possible. It doesn't take much calculation to prove for $n=2$ that we simply need $$ U_1^\dagger U_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & k \\ -k & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Indeed we might as well work with special unitary matrices here so you can take $k=1$. Then you simply take any $U_1$ you like and set $U_2 = U_1 \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.
I can't see an obvious candidate for $n=4$.
Lastly, I don't think trying to work with vector fields is helping you here and since everything here is just a matrix Lie group or matrix Lie algebra you can just use that.

This is a very nice way of looking at it, thank you! Especially with the determinant. I am lucky that in my actual case I have a sum of $>2$ terms, so it could still work, but you just gave me a nice very intuitive way of proving why my set of unitary matrices has to be larger than 2 if we are dealing with odd dimensions. Thank you for this, I appreciate it. In my case, I still have to evaluate how many summands I will actually need to have, but this is already nice to show that it has to be larger than 2 for simple reasons.
