Do unitary adjoint representations on $\mathfrak{sl}$ form a ring?
I am not too deep into abstract algebra, but I need it badly for my PhD. Therefore, I would be happy for some help here!
I try to give some sense into:
Let $\mathrm{Ad}_{g*}M= U^\dagger M U$ be a unitary adjoint representation of a Lie group  $\mathrm{SL}(n)$, $g\in\mathrm{SL}(n)$ acting on the associated Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, $M\in \mathfrak{sl}$. Since the adjoint representation is a map $G\rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{T}_e \mathrm{SL}(n))$ and the space of automorphisms is a vector space, which can be seen by noting that the trace of $\mathrm{Ad}_{g*}M$ and the trace of $$(\mathrm{Ad}_{g_1*}+\mathrm{Ad}_{g_2*})M=U_1^\dagger M U_1+U_2^\dagger M U_2$$
is zero I was wondering what algebraic structure I can give to this $(\mathrm{Ad}_{g_1*}+\mathrm{Ad}_{g_2*})$.
I noted that this is probably a smooth function acting on $M$, since we are dealing with pushforwards of left and right translation which are defined to be smooth on a Lie group.
I was wondering, if I can define this to be a ring, because it looks like one to me (still have to prove it) and if therefore I am dealing with a something like a "ring action" in accordance with a group action?
Is this even defined? I read about things being modules where one may interpret this as a ring action, but I have never had any contact with that.
Is there some already existing literature/has someone been dealing with "additions of adjoint representations"?
Please help me give this some mathematical sense so I can go on with my analysis. I am kind of stuck here and I don't know what to read, Google does not help either for this and I have nowhere seen additions of adjoint representations.

The space of automorphisms is not a vector space.  The space of endomorphisms is an algebra, and, although the image of the adjoint representation is not a ring, you can certainly look at the subring it generates—which turns out to be everything.  Is that your question?

@LSpice oh I am sorry, isn't the adjoint representation living in the space of automorphisms? I think I read this in the representation book of Fulton. And where do my $\mathrm{Ad}{g_1*}+\mathrm{Ad}{g_2*}$ live? is this the subring you were talking about? And is there then some mathematical model such as "group actions on a space" but instead of group elements I would have $\mathrm{Ad}{g_1*}+\mathrm{Ad}{g_2*}$ elements which are - if I understood you correctly - subring elements? Thank you so much in advance. I would be glad for literature for this as well.

Re, yes, the adjoint representation acts by automorphisms, but sums of automorphisms need no longer be automorphisms (consider $I + (-I)$), so we do not say that the (‘multiplicative’) group of automorphisms forms a vector space, or even an additive group.  Yes, as long as you are willing to work with endomorphisms rather than automorphisms, you can add different elements of the image (though the result need no longer be in the image).  …

… This perspective suggests replacing the representations of a group $G$ by the representations of a suitable algebra of functions on $G$, such as the Schwartz space.  Probably just about any text on the representations of Lie groups, for example Varadarajan - An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis on Semisimple Lie Groups, discusses this—though I don't have access to that specific book to check.

@LSpice Thank you I will surely check this out. Yes I am willing to work with endomorphisms instead of automorphisms, absolutely. So, my sum of adjoint representations live in the space of endomorphisms. I did not quite catch what you meant now by replacing it with an algebra and Schwartz space? Could you elaborate what you mean please? And how can I still regard this as a "group" action or ring action or whatever, something of this kind.

In the setting of real groups, for example, a smooth action $\pi$ of a reductive Lie group $G$ on a vector space $V$ can be converted to an action $\pi_\infty$ of the Schwartz space $\mathcal S$ of $G$ on the space of smooth vectors $V^\infty$ by $\pi_\infty(f)(v) = \int_G f(g)\pi(g)(v)\mathrm dg$.  This is now a representation of an algebra.  My expertise is in $p$-adic groups, not real groups, but, if the appropriate analogy holds, then the image of $\pi_\infty$ is the subring of endomorphisms of $V$ generated by the image of $\pi$.

It seems you are elaborating your previous question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/469818/i-am-stuck-tips-for-how-i-can-proceed-with-my-lie-theoretical-problem but, as the comments there and here show your notation is not helping. There is a $g^*$ subindex that I don't get in your equality that defines the adjoint representation. Moreover, your matrix $M$ should live in the Lie group (the domain of the representation), hence it should be invertible and traceless if that is what you mean, for example, a Sylvester-Pauli matrix or a Gell-Mann Pauli matrix. Since these matrices are unitary ...

... and the matrix $U$ is also unitary, perhaps you mean to have the adjoint representation of $\operatorname{SU}_n$? with codomain its Lie algebra ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak u}_n$ and then extend to is complexification ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_n$?

@LSpice and concretely, this would mean for this here if I understood you correctly, that I may rewrite $$\mathrm{Ad}{g_1*}+\mathrm{Ad}{g_2*}$$ in terms of an integral like $$(\mathrm{Ad}{g_1*}+\mathrm{Ad}{g_2*})v=\int (f_1(g_1)\pi(g_1)+f_2(g_2)\pi(g_2))(v)\mathrm{d}g$$ ? Did you mean that?

@FZaldivar would you care to elabore what why you think my matrix should live in the Lie group instead of the Lie algebra? Notation-wise: $Ad_{g'*}$ denotes the pushforward of $\mathrm{Ad}_{g'}(g)=g'gg^{-1}$

@LSpice what do you think about modules in this context? I have not dealt with modules at all but from what I have seen, a module seems like exactly that, a vector space and a ring acting on it. In this case, the vector space would be $\mathfrak{sl}$ and the ring would be the subring of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ consisting of additions of adjoint representations. Would this also be a framework for my problem?

Ah maybe not, modules don't take a ring action on a space but on an abelian group apparently, which we clearly don't have here...

@LSpice or did you mean something like $\phi_{{i}}(P)=\int \mathrm{d}g\sum_i^n \delta(g-g_i)U^\dagger_i P U_i$ where $g_i$ is defined as in $\mathrm{Ad}_{g_i*}(P)=U_i^\dagger P U_i$

Re, yes (except that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are both $g$); I don't know if this can be achieved  exactly, but at least it can be achieved in the limit. (This latter is essentially what you are saying here; the $\delta$ distribution can be viewed as a limit of bump functions in a suitable topology.) Re, yes, you can view the vector space (which is also an Abelian group) $V^\infty$ as a module for the Schwartz space.

@LSpice ok so I can rewrite my $\phi$ with an integral. Would you see any advantage in this form? Are there properties of Schwartz functions that I can exploit now? Does this give us any more insights / more possibilities of analysis? I guess distribution theory can now play into this - does this yield any benefits? Are there useful theorems that can now be applied?

@LSpice I think I got it now. Rewriting my representation in terms of the integral in the Schwartz space, and the measure being the Haar measure in this case, I think what I am dealing with is a question whether I have a unitary 1-design or not. This is actually now the real question that I have been looking for. Do you agree?

Re, of course I'm not in a position to say what you meant (and I don't know the definition of "unitary 1-design" for a representation of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$, which isn't compact doesn't preserve a nice inner product on $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$), but I'm glad if this discussion helped you formulate your question!

Yes I know it is not compact, but it is locally compact, which suffices for the Haar measure to be defined (according to my book). Yes, I have really been looking for weeks now how to formulate my actual problem until I came upon these designs. Was a journey. I will read into this representation in the Schwartz space, if there may occur additional questions, may I contact you? @LSpice

Re, yes, there is a Haar measure on $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$, but, unlike the compact case, one runs into potential trouble with convergence issues when discussing averaging over it.  But more fundamental is the fact that, contrary to what you say, $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb C)$ does not operate by unitaries.  I think you might mean something more like what @FZaldivar suggests.

@LSpice as far as I have understood now, my adjoint representations live in the space of endomorphisms, more precisely in the subring they generate and the unitary matrices involved in the representation should - apart from being unitary - be traceless as well. I don't think the restriction to $\det U = 1$ is necessary here and the Lie algebra of $SU(n)$ would be skrew-Hermitian matrices, which we don't want here. And I can express my representations in the Schwartz space with the Haar measure as well as you suggested, giving it an integral expression.

@LSpice would you be so nice and give me some literature where I can look up the conversion you desribed from a smooth action on a vector space to a Schwartz space? And what is $f$ then here, is it our bump function, which is in the limit the delta function? How would you write that? I would need this since I will be presenting this next week but I have not found (understandable) literature here, I know that it is true what you are saying but I don't know how to use it/write it down/make the analogy to $f$ has to be delta function here. Would appreciate it!

Re, real groups are not my particular speciality, so I have nothing to recommend but the general references.  I would start with Varadarajan, which I mentioned before, but that's just because I learned from it at some point; any book on harmonic analysis on Lie groups would probably be as good a starting point.
